# Python: concatenate 2 image with partial blend

Tags: python, image, opencv, concatenation, blending

I need to read images from 2 cameras with python (opencv). I would like to concatenate the 2 images in 1 single image. I can easly do this

> frame = np.concatenate((cam1,cam2), axis=1)

Now I want to blend the last 20 pixels of the first camera with the first 20 pixels of the second one. Is it possible? How can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with *blend*? And why 20 pixels? Is that a row?

Comment: I mean merge the 2 portions of the images with some transparency. With 20 pixel I mean the columns. The column (large 20 pixels) at the end of the first image and the column (20 pixels) at the beginning of the second image.

Comment: Do you want to blend the images with a constant alpha (like 50% for all 20 columns) or with a smooth transition?